# Export csv-coordinates to JSON - square brackets

Tags: leaflet, coordinates, csv, json

I´ve got multiple point-layers that I want to join in a single JSON-file used for webmapping. The layers is to be listed in column by column like this:

[55.778659,12.151137  ],    [55.77272358,12.14963029  ],

Is this the right setup when it comes to separators (commas)?

It's for Leaflet.

Comment: Read the [GeoJSON spec](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html). It gives very clear examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [JSON standard](http://json.org/) and [GeoJSON standard](http://geojson.org/) - they specify everything from commas to brackets to property fields in the geographical data.